# C++11 make_shared instancing

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Apologies for the long question, but some context is necessary.  I have a bit of code that seems to be a useful pattern for the project I'm working on:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo( int bar = 1 );
    ~Foo();
    typedef std::shared_ptr< Foo > pointer_type;
    static pointer_type make( int bar = 1 )
    {
        return std::make_shared< Foo >( bar );
    }

...
}
```

As you can see, it provides a straightforward way of constructing any class as a PointerType which encapsulates a shared_ptr to that type:

```
auto oneFoo = Foo::make( 2 );
```

And therefore you get the advantages of shared_ptr without putting references to make_shared and shared_ptr all over the code base.

Encapsulating the smart pointer type within the class provides several advantages:

1. It lets you control the copyability and moveability of the pointer types.
2. It hides the shared_ptr details from callers, so that non-trivial object constructions, such as those that throw exceptions, can be placed within the Instance() call.
3. You can change the underlying smart pointer type when you're working with projects that use multiple smart pointer implementations.  You could switch to a unique_ptr or even to raw pointers for a particular class, and calling code would remain the same.
4. It concentrates the details about (smart) pointer construction and aliasing within the class that knows most about how to do it.
5. It lets you decide which classes can use smart pointers and which classes must be constructed on the stack.  The existence of the PointerType field provides a hint to callers about what types of pointers can be created that correspond for the class.  If there is no PointerType defined for a class, this would indicate that no pointers to that class may be created; therefore that particular class must be created on the stack, RAII style.

However, I see no obvious way of applying this bit of code to all the classes in my project without typing the requisite typedef and static PointerType Instance() functions directly.  I suspect there should be some consistent, C++11 standard, cross-platform way of doing this with policy-based templates, but a bit of experimentation has not turned up an obvious way of applying this trivially to a bunch of classes in a way that compiles cleanly on all modern C++ compilers.

Can you think of an elegant way to add these concepts to a bunch of classes, without a great deal of cutting and pasting?  An ideal solution would conceptually limit what types of pointers can be created for which types of classes (one class uses shared_ptr and another uses raw pointers), and it would also handle instancing of any supported type by its own preferred method.  Such a solution might even handle and/or limit coercion, by failing appropriately at compile time, between non-standard and standard smart and dumb pointer types.

Comment: TBH I don't see what you are doing as being any less work than simply using `std::make_shared` directly.

Comment: Wrapping the make_shared in a static function permits you to do other things, such as non-constructor initialization.  It additionally allows you to do a neat trick of storing a weak_ptr to this within each class, which comes in handy when informing other classes about *this while staying within the shared_ptr domain.  Lastly, this pattern abstracts details about shared_ptr from consumers of the class, which permits swapping shared_ptr for some other local smart pointer class.

Comment: If you want the weak pointer to this, you might want to consider deriving from std::enable_shared_from_this.

Comment: What do you mean by non-constructor initialization? When you call the static function the make_shared will still call Foo's constructor, right? You don't have to call it directly I guess. What is that useful for?

Comment: Unless you're using `shared_from_this`, a factory should actually return a `std::unique_ptr`, because the returned pointer is the only pointer to the particular object.  It's easy to get a `shared_ptr` from a `unique_ptr`, while the reverse is not at all possible.

Comment: @Ben, if I could thumbs down a comment, I would.  Don't mix unique and shared pointers to the same object. The factory is fine to return a shared_ptr.  Shared means more that one thing *might* point to the object, not that more than one thing *must* point to it.

Comment: @RobL I think he means that a `std::unique_ptr` can be moved into a `std::shared_ptr`, thereby transferring ownership. The reverse is not possible for obvious reasons.

Comment: @BenVoigt problem with transferring `std::unique_ptr` to `std::shared_ptr` - memory fragmentation, that you may want to avoid.

Comment: @Slava: You mean the fact that the metadata object and the user object can be placed in one allocation by `make_shared`?

Comment: @BenVoigt yes indeed

Comment: @Slava: If you're worried about efficiency at that level, you should be preferring to avoid `shared_ptr` in the first place.  `unique_ptr` has a lot lower overhead.  If you *need* the reference counting, go ahead and use `make_shared`, but this should not be your primary tool.

Comment: @BenVoigt I cannot avoid `shared_ptr` if I need shared ownership. So `std::unique_ptr` may be preferrable to return in some cases, but it depends on situation. But to prefer it in general, no matter what and transfer to `shared_ptr` if necessary - I would say that is a wrong advise.

Comment: @Slava: If this class will only ever be used via `shared_ptr`, then inherit `shared_from_this` and return `shared_ptr` from the factory (like my first comment said).  If it is potentially useful apart from `shared_ptr`, then making a factory function to call `make_shared` is foolish (yes, I know it's the whole premise of the question -- but I'm hoping the question is actually about consistency, in which case consistently returning `unique_ptr` from a factory is better, and not just saving of 7 characters)

Answer (score 10):

One way is to use the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

```
template<typename T>
struct shared_factory
{
    using pointer_type = std::shared_ptr<T>;

    template<typename... Args>
    static pointer_type make(Args&&... args)
    {
        return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

struct foo : public shared_factory<foo>
{
    foo(char const*, int) {}
};
```

I believe this gives you what you want.

```
foo::pointer_type f = foo::make("hello, world", 42);
```

### However...

I wouldn't recommend using this approach. Attempting to dictate how users of a type instantiate the type is unnecessarily restrictive. If they need a `std::shared_ptr`, they can create one. If they need a `std::unique_ptr`, they can create one. If they want to create an object on the stack, they can. I see nothing to be gained by mandating how your users' objects are created and managed.

To address your points:

> 1. It lets you control the copyability and moveability of the pointer types.

Of what benefit is this?

> 2. It hides the shared_ptr details from callers, so that non-trivial object constructions, such as those that throw exceptions, can be placed within the Instance() call.

I'm not sure what you mean here. Hopefully not that you can catch the exception and return a `nullptr`. That would be Java-grade bad.

> 3. You can change the underlying smart pointer type when you're working with projects that use multiple smart pointer implementations. You could switch to a unique_ptr or even to raw pointers for a particular class, and calling code would remain the same.

If you are working with multiple kinds of smart pointer, perhaps it would be better to let the user choose the appropriate kind for a given situation. Besides, I'd argue that having the same calling code but returning different kinds of handle is potentially confusing.

> 4. It concentrates the details about (smart) pointer construction and aliasing within the class that knows most about how to do it.

In what sense does a class know "most" about how to do pointer construction and aliasing?

> 5. It lets you decide which classes can use smart pointers and which classes must be constructed on the stack. The existence of the PointerType field provides a hint to callers about what types of pointers can be created that correspond for the class. If there is no PointerType defined for a class, this would indicate that no pointers to that class may be created; therefore that particular class must be created on the stack, RAII style.

Again, I disagree fundamentally with the idea that objects of a certain type *must* be created and managed in a certain way. This is one of the reasons why the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is so insidious.

Comment: In this example you're returning a std::shared_ptr<T>, but in the future you could change that typedef to another smart pointer and then change what's returned by the function, right?

Comment: @mock_blatt Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: @johnwbyrd Totally revised my answer. I think it gives you a solution. However, I was morally obliged to put a warning, lest my advice be used for evil.

Comment: @JosephThomson Yours is a good, but partial, answer.  The curiously recurring template pattern is definitely a step in the right direction.  I'm interested in extending it so that the pointer_type may be specified as an external trait, so that the shared_factory can have more knowledge about which kinds of pointers can be created for which kinds of objects.  Of course, nothing stops a consumer from doing an end-run around the class policy and using raw pointers and whatever, but this does at least provide a recommendation as to what they should and shouldn't...

Comment: @JosephThomson Can you think of a way to abstract details of the pointer_type so that we can limit or encourage casting between specific pointer_types for any class or set of classes?  I'm thinking traits but the answer is not obvious to me.  I imagine a template that permits smart pointers to be quietly swapped out for handles, with no changes to the class itself.  (Maybe we need a new nomenclature to refer to a thing that can be a smart pointer, raw pointer, reference or handle.)

Comment: @JosephThomson As I consider the problem further, it might be the case that we could use some external policy that describes each pointer type, and also describes the kinds of casts that are legal for that pointer type.  You could then feed that policy to your factory, which would in turn churn out a pointer_type for each class that knows a lot more details about what it can be cast to and from.  This would permit a class to simultaneously support, or refuse to support, new and legacy pointer and reference types.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want? What do you mean by limiting or encouraging casting between pointer types? It sounds like you are going to need to write your own smart pointers, or at least wrappers around the standard smart pointers (probably best: writing correct smart pointers is difficult). Can you also elaborate on what you mean by `shared_factory` knowing about which pointers can be created? And what do you mean by quietly swapping out?

Comment: I would just delete the top half of your answer. Starting from "However..." is all spot on, A+, would read again, have an upvote.

Comment: Although I don't agree with all your reasoning, clearly you have given a lot of non-trivial thought to my question.  Thank you, bounty awarded.

Comment: @johnwbyrd Thanks! I didn't further refine my answer because I was waiting for a response from you, as I was not particularly sure what you wanted.

Comment: @JosephThomson To be completely honest, since I'm reaching for a concept that doesn't practically exist at the moment (encapsulating pointer/reference/handle types generically in classes), it is probably most accurate to say that I don't know what I want.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't advise adding those static functions.  Among other drawbacks, they really get pretty burdensome to create and maintain when there are multiple constructors.  This is a case where auto can help as well as a typedef outside the class.  Plus, you can use the std namespace (but please not in the header):

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
    Foo( int bar = 1 );

...
}

typedef std::shared_ptr<Foo> FooPtr;
```

In the C++ file:

```
using namespace std;
auto oneFoo = make_shared<Foo>( 2 );
FooPtr anotherFoo = make_shared<Foo>( 2 );
```

I think you'll find this to not be too burdensome on typing.  Of course, this is all a matter of style.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier in the question, this approach means you are scattering shared_ptr and make_shared references all over the codebase.   This unfortunately locks you into C++11 shared_ptr types.  Can you think of a way of hiding those details in the classes themselves, so that external code doesn't have to keep track of pointer implementation details?

Comment: I suppose if that was your goal, you'd just write your own smart pointer implementation and use that. Then you can change the internals as needed. The equivalent to your simple example is your own smart pointer template that just spits out a shared pointer, but you could change that if desired. With your current approach, imagine the disaster if you do decide to change the implementation across many classes in many projects.

Comment: @johnwbyrd Could you use a type alias and wrap `make_shared` in your own function if you want the flexibility to use a different smart pointer later?

Comment: That would certainly be possible, but I suggest that it should be up to the class itself to decide what a smart pointer for that class should look like.  In my current use case, I have an older code base that uses its own custom smart pointer, and I have some new C++11 code that wants shared_ptrs for everything.  Thanks to both of you for continuing to think about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a refinement of Joseph's answer for the sake of making the kind of pointer more configurable:

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T, template <typename...> class PtrT = std::shared_ptr>
struct ptr_factory {
    using pointer_type = PtrT<T>;

    template <typename... Args>
    static pointer_type make(Args&&... args) {
        return pointer_type{new T{args...}};
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct ptr_factory<T, std::shared_ptr> {
    using pointer_type = std::shared_ptr<T>;

    template <typename... Args>
    static pointer_type make(Args&&... args) {
        return std::make_shared<T>(args...);
    }
};

struct foo : public ptr_factory<foo> {
        foo(char const*, int) {}
};

struct bar : public ptr_factory<bar, std::unique_ptr> {
    bar(char const*, int) {}
};
```

`ptr_factory` defaults to using `std::shared_ptr`, but can be configured to use different smart pointer templates, thanks to template template parameters, as illustrated by `struct bar`.

Comment: I doubt that benefit of using custom smart pointer will outperform benefits of using `std::make_shared`.

Comment: @Slava: A pointer without reference counting will definitely outperform `make_shared`.  The allocation-combining reduces the overhead of the reference-count metadata, but can't eliminate the repeated access to it -- your performance is still going to pay for the counting logic.

Comment: @BenVoigt it will outperform if I do not need shared ownership. If I do then I am loosing higher efficiency of `std::unique_ptr` and better memory allocation from `std::make_shared`

Comment: @Slava I think `std::make_shared` is just syntax sugar and explicitly constructing them does not have any disadvantages.

Comment: @kamikaze you think wrong "In contrast to that expression, std::make_shared<T> typically allocates memory for the T object and for the std::shared_ptr's control block with a single memory allocation (this is a non-binding requirement in the Standard), where std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(args...)) performs at least two memory allocations."

Comment: @Slava OK, I didn't know that. I added a specialisation to address this.

Comment: @kamikaze This is a good and intelligent improvement on Joseph's answer. I wish I could award partial bounty credit for it, as you have correctly captured the spirit of the question. Sadly, stackoverflow doesn't permit me to split the bounty, but I acknowledge publicly that it is worth some or all of the bounty.

Comment: @johnwbyrd Ratings are overrated. Don't worry about it.