# enable_shared_from_this not initialized while using shared_ptr from unique_ptr to base class. why?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class base {
public:
  virtual void method() = 0;
  virtual ~base() = default;
};

class test: public base, public std::enable_shared_from_this<test> {
private:
  std::string text;
public:
  test(std::string text): text(std::move(text)) {}
  ~test() = default;
  virtual void method() override {
    std::cout << "text: " << text;
    std::cout << " this: " << this->shared_from_this().get() << std::endl;
  }
  static std::unique_ptr<base> create(std::string text) {
    return std::unique_ptr<base>(new test(std::move(text)));
  }
};

static auto create_test(std::string text) {
  return test::create(std::move(text));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::shared_ptr<base> shared = create_test("some text");
  shared->method();
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this program I get exception "bad_weak_ptr".
Could you explain why "enable_shared_from_this" is not initialized?

When I change instances of `unique_ptr<base>` to `unique_ptr<test>` it works.

```
$ ./test 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr'
   what():  bad_weak_ptr
text: some textAborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Although I've previously said that factory functions should return a `unique_ptr`, that does require that pointer isn't already shared at the point of return from the factory.  If your class inherits `shared_from_this`, then there already are two pointers when the factory returns.  In fact, [I explicitly called that case out in my original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953783/c11-make-shared-instancing#comment59565062_35953783)  So contact whoever advised you to use `unique_ptr` and `shared_from_this` together and tell them there's an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What else did you expect? You are using `shared_ptr<base>`. Base is not inhereted from `enable_shared_from_this`, so it's shared pointer can not initialize weak reference which is used by `shared_from_this`.

Works exactly as designed.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast a shared pointer built out of a `test` to one to `base` using this `create` function:

```
static std::shared_ptr<base> create(std::string text) {
    return std::shared_ptr<test>(new test(std::move(text)));
}
```

Otherwise, it won't work.
`enable_shared_from_this` works as expected, but consider [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this):

> std::enable_shared_from_this allows an object t that is currently managed by a std::shared_ptr named pt to safely generate additional std::shared_ptr instances pt1, pt2, ... that all share ownership of t with pt.

In your code, you aren't creating any `shared_pointer` out of a `test`.
The `create` function above does the job.